# Convert column of data to comma separated cells of data based on record file presence

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, images

I have to migrate a database from one format to another.
The servers accept the data in different formats.
The current issue is image URL files.

```
DATA BASE 1) = WHERE IMAGES WERE DOWNLOADED FROM
DATA BASE 2) = TARGET DATA BASE TO UPLOAD TO
```

DATABASE 1)

- Produced a download csv. spreadsheet file with the record identified in column header A1 "sku" and Column header B1 "url"
- The "sku" value :"toy-blue-boat" in cell A2 could have an number of associated image URLs 0-100
- The download sheet would place all the individual URLs in the "url" Column B2-B101

In this example with 100 image URLs for the first SKU; the next SKU would appear on row 102 column A
`"sku": "toy-red-car"` and it too would have 100 image URLs associated with it fill column `B102-B202`

This would be repeated for several other SKUs - each with 100 image URLs in column B "url"

- "yellow-toy-giraffe", "green-nijia-turtle", "orange-bounce-ball".

```
A1 sku
A2 "toy-blue-boat"
...
A201 "toy-red-car"
...
A301 "yellow-toy-giraffe"
...
A401 "green-nijia-turtle"
...
A501 "orange-bounce-ball"
```

Each separated by 100 blank spaces in column A
Column

```
B1 "url"
B2  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-blue-boat-1.jpeg
B3  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-blue-boat-2.jpeg
B4  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-blue-boat-3.jpeg
B5  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-blue-boat-4.jpeg
...
B101 www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-blue-boat-100.jpeg
B102  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-red-car-1.jpeg
B103  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-red-car-2.jpeg
B104  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-red-car-3.jpeg
B105  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-red-car-4.jpeg
...
B201 www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-red-car-100.jpeg
B202  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/yellow-toy-giraffe-1.jpeg
B203  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/yellow-toy-giraffe-2.jpeg
B204  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/yellow-toy-giraffe-3.jpeg
B205  www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/yellow-toy-giraffe-4.jpeg
...
B301 www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/yellow-toy-giraffe-100.jpeg
ETC.
```

The PROBLEM is server two only accepts the URL data in a single row with the data in a single ";" semi-colon separated cell.

```
A1 sku                   
A2 "toy-blue-boat"       
A3 "toy-red-car"
A4 "yellow-toy-giraffe"
A5 "green-nijia-turtle"
A6 "orange-bounce-ball"

B1 url
B2 www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-blue-boat-1.jpeg;www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-...TO 100
B2 www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-red-car-1.jpeg;www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/toy-...TO 100
B3 www.//where-is-my-image-AWS3/yellow-toy-giraffe-100.jpeg;B301 www.//where-is-my-TO 100
ETC.
```

QUESTION TO SUPER USERS.
IS THERE A METHOD WITHIN EXCEL FORMULAS or WITH VBA or WITH ANOTHER PROGRAM
to apply to the data of DATABASE 1)
To create in Column C such that; wherever a new SKU is presented. In this case C2 / C102 / C202 / C302 / C402 ETC.
a cell with the semi-colon separated data for the associated URLS to the sku in that row of column C?
If that is all that happens i can take it from there.
OR, if easier...
Simply processes the data to allow it to be accepted by DATABASE 2) formatting and it appears on a separate sheet of the same Excel Workbook - or other program.

******(Que music from Mission Impossible)******

Any ideas are welcome.

ps. i do have excel 365 functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: You can easily create a table in Power Query (`Get & Transform`) which will create your output. You'd have to refresh the query whenever you changed the data in columns A or B.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub urlSwitchaRoo()

Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
Dim dstSheet As Worksheet
Dim urlString As String
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

x = 2

Set srcSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set dstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
rowCount = srcSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


dstSheet.Cells(2, "A") = srcSheet.Cells(2, "A")
urlString = srcSheet.Cells(2, "B").Value

For i = 3 To rowCount

    If srcSheet.Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then
        dstSheet.Cells(x, "B").Value = urlString
        x = x + 1
        dstSheet.Cells(x, "A") = srcSheet.Cells(i, "A")
        urlString = srcSheet.Cells(i, "B")
    Else
        urlString = urlString & ";" & srcSheet.Cells(i, "B")
    End If

Next i

dstSheet.Cells(x, "B").Value = urlString

End Sub
```

I know you implied every sku has 100 urls, I thought I would not hard code that rule, and I went with a dynamic number of urls, with a value appearing in Column A trigging the next new group of urls.

Additionally I used one workbook, with sheets, if you need them in differnt workbooks, then just adjust the set srcSheet/dstSheet to be the workbooks you want.  Or keep it the way it is, then move the worksheet once it has been generated to a new workbook.

I guess that makes me Tom Cruise , can I be Bond instead, so I get the girl as well :)

*******BONUS INFO**

During testing  I had created a excel sheet with 78000 rows, and a new sku ever 23 rows.  I added a timer to the function.

When using & to join the URL's the time averaged approx 1.2 seconds.
When using + to join the URL's the time average approx 1.35 seconds.

So the answer to the question of what is best way to join strings in VBA, is & by a whisker.